# Method parameter assignment in C#

Tags: c#, assignment-operator

Given the below code, will the method parameter y in Bar(int y) be assigned the value from x or 1?  I realize they are logically equivalent, but I want to understand the assignment operation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var x = 0;
        foo.Bar(x = 1);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(int y)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter gets the value of the assignment.

Consider code like this:

```
int x = 0;
int y = (x = 1);
x = 42;
foo.Bar(y);
```

Eventhough `x` is changed another time, `y` still contains `1`.

Comment: All good answers, but I found this the most clear and concise.  Marked as answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's assigned to the result of `x=1` which equals 1.

Answer (score 3):

The result of the assignment operator will be passed to `Bar`, which "is the value that was assigned to the left-hand side" (from [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple.aspx)).

In this case, that is the `int` value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the order of evaluation. Before calling a function, any expression, within the braces need to be evaluated. The result is then used as an argument in the function call.

In your case, the `x = 1` is an expression. It needs to be evaluated to an assignment first `(x=1)` then you can use the resulting value which is x and use it as an argument to `bar`.

It is equivalent to

```
x = 1
foo.bar(x)
```

You can see that it will be evaluated if you look at the value of `x` after the call to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside the () will be passed to y, so long as its an int.

But I think to directly answer the question, x is what actually gets passed, not 1, x is equal to 1, to then y=x=1.

Comment: The result of the assignment gets passed, not the value of `x`.